# Debian: Install exim4. 'Debian-exim' is not a valid group name

Tags: debian, exim

I'm trying to install exim4 and here's the output of the command `sudo apt-get install exim4`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
exim4 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 60 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Setting up exim4-config (4.84.2-2+deb8u4) ...
Adding system-user for exim (v4)
                       groupadd: 'Debian-exim' is not a valid group name
adduser: `/usr/sbin/groupadd -g 115 Debian-exim' returned error code 3. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package exim4-config (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of exim4-base:
 exim4-base depends on exim4-config (>= 4.82) | exim4-config-2; however:
  Package exim4-config is not configured yet.
  Package exim4-config-2 is not installed.
  Package exim4-config which provides exim4-config-2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package exim4-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of exim4-daemon-light:
 exim4-daemon-light depends on exim4-base (>= 4.84.2); however:
  Package exim4-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package exim4-daemon-light (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of exim4:
 exim4 depends on exim4-base (>= 4.84.2-2+deb8u4); however:
  Package exim4-base is not configured yet.
 exim4 depends on exim4-base (<< 4.84.2-2+deb8u4.1); however:
  Package exim4-base is not configured yet.
 exim4 depends on exim4-daemon-light | exim4-daemon-heavy | exim4-daemon-custom; however:
  Package exim4-daemon-light is not configured yet.
  Package exim4-daemon-heavy is not installed.
  Package exim4-daemon-custom is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package exim4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mailutils:
 mailutils depends on default-mta | mail-transport-agent; however:
  Package default-mta is not installed.
  Package exim4-daemon-light which provides default-mta is not configured yet.
  Package mail-transport-agent is not installed.
  Package exim4-daemon-light which provides mail-transport-agent is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mailutils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 exim4-config
 exim4-base
 exim4-daemon-light
 exim4
 mailutils
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The first failure is `'Debian-exim' is not a valid group name`

In the script `/var/lib/dpkg/info/exim4-config.postinst`, I found the command which raise error:

```
adduser --system --group --quiet --home /var/spool/exim4 --no-create-home --disabled-login --force-badname Debian-exim
```

The output of this command is

```
groupadd: 'Debian-exim' is not a valid group name
adduser: `/usr/sbin/groupadd -g 115 Debian-exim' returned error code 3. Exiting.
```

Before that, I was able to install Exim4 on three machines. At this time I think I'm doing everything same.

I have no idea why group with uppercase character doesn't want to be created with option `--force-badname`.

How to solve this problem and create this system group?

```
Debian GNU/Linux 8.8 (jessie)
```

**Update**

I have an assumption that the command `adduser --group` is working over `groupadd`, which doesn't support the option `--force-badname`. But I still do not know what to do with it.

Comment: Do you maybe already have a group with gid 115?

Comment: @Ginnungagap No, I don't.

Comment: I solved this problem. I launched a new Debian server. The problem was not reproduced on it. Then I copied the files `/usr/sbin/groupadd` and `/usr/sbin/useradd` from the new server to the server with the problem. After that I managed to create a group `Debian-exim`.

The reason for the problem:
I configure server by ansible and some of tasks changes `groupadd` and `useradd`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue when I was installing backuppc.

I replaced `adduser` with `addgroup` in the above command and Debain-exim group name was created. After that the installation was successful

```
addgroup --system --group --quiet --home /var/spool/exim4 --no-create-home --disabled-login --force-badname Debian-exim
```

Notes:

1. I did not check if the arguments are appropriate to `addgroup` but I did not get an error
2. I also removed the `--quiet` argument so I could see what happened

Comment: Saved my a$$! thank you!